# Upload file to OSS bucket from appBundle

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I'm running a workitem, which initiates a predefined activity in Inventor. The activity is to open a template assembly file from appBundle, modify certain parameters and save a copy of it. After the copy is saved I want the files to be uploaded to OSS bucket.

I used HttpClient.PutAsync method to stream the file content to url but that  didn't work. Got the status as "Waiting for Activation". Can anybody correct my mistake or give any feasible solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Open Network** is still in **Preview** for **Inventor**. Please contact us on **aps.help@autodesk.com** to get it enabled for your app - more info here on what you have to do before it can be enabled for your app:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/open-network-preview